# In mocha unit test, how to mock a global variable?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

How are you doing?

I am developing unit tests with mocha, and I need to mock a global variable.

```
let logger = {
    info: () => ({}),
};

exports.findCallCenters = (req, res, next) => {
    logger.info("findCallCenters", req.params);
};
```

When I run my test, it says that `logger` is `undefined`. That's why I need to mock it.

I don't know how to proceed to test my function.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334948/4248342

Comment: Thank you @HardikModham I'll try!

Comment: *When I run my test, it says that logger is undefined* - but it is defined in the same scope, `let logger = ...`. Where's a global?

Comment: Could you share your test file source code?